# Relation between braided Hopf algebra and usual Hopf algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

What are the relations between braided Hopf algebra and usual Hopf algebra?

Acoording to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_Hopf_algebra), a braided Hopf algebra is defined as follows.

Let H be a Hopf algebra over a field $k$, and assume that the antipode of $H$ is bijective. A Yetter–Drinfeld module $R$ over $H$ is called a braided bialgebra in the Yetter–Drinfeld category ${}_{H}^{H}{\mathcal  {YD}}$ if
${\displaystyle (R,\cdot ,\eta )}$ is a unital associative algebra, where the multiplication map ${\displaystyle \cdot :R\times R\to R}$ and the unit ${\displaystyle \eta :k\to R}$ are maps of Yetter–Drinfeld modules,
${\displaystyle (R,\Delta ,\varepsilon )}$ is a coassociative coalgebra with counit ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$, and both $\Delta$  and ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$  are maps of Yetter–Drinfeld modules,
the maps ${\displaystyle \Delta :R\to R\otimes R}$ and ${\displaystyle \varepsilon :R\to k}$ are algebra maps in the category ${}_{H}^{H}{\mathcal  {YD}}$, where the algebra structure of ${\displaystyle R\otimes R}$ is determined by the unit ${\displaystyle \eta \otimes \eta (1):k\to R\otimes R}$ and the multiplication map
\begin{align}
(R\otimes R)\times (R\otimes R)\to R\otimes R,\quad (r\otimes s,t\otimes u)\mapsto \sum _{i}rt_{i}\otimes s_{i}u,
\end{align}
and
$$
c(s\otimes t)=\sum _{i}t_{i}\otimes s_{i}. (R\otimes R)\times (R\otimes R)\to R\otimes R,\quad (r\otimes s,t\otimes u)\mapsto \sum _{i}rt_{i}\otimes s_{i}u,
$$
and
$$
c(s\otimes t)=\sum _{i}t_{i}\otimes s_{i}. 
$$
Here $c$ is the canonical braiding in the Yetter–Drinfeld category ${\displaystyle {}_{H}^{H}{\mathcal {YD}}}$.
A braided bialgebra in ${\displaystyle {}_{H}^{H}{\mathcal {YD}}}$ is called a braided Hopf algebra, if there is a morphism ${\displaystyle S:R\to R}$ of Yetter–Drinfeld modules such that
$$
{\displaystyle S(r^{(1)})r^{(2)}=r^{(1)}S(r^{(2)})=\eta (\varepsilon (r))} {\displaystyle S(r^{(1)})r^{(2)}=r^{(1)}S(r^{(2)})=\eta (\varepsilon (r))}$$ 
for all ${\displaystyle r\in R,}$
where $${\displaystyle \Delta _{R}(r)=r^{(1)}\otimes r^{(2)}}$$ is the Sweedler notation.

The usual Hopf algebra is a braided Hopf algebra when the braiding is permutation. Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: this should be migrated to mathoverflow (imo).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_Hopf_algebra) a braided Hopf algebra as:

> "...a Hopf algebra in a braided monoidal category"

and describes the "*braided bialgebras in the Yetter–Drinfeld category ${}_{H}^{H}{\mathcal  {YD}}$*" mentioned in your post, as "the most common" example.

However, the notion of **braided Hopf algebra** (i.e.: **a Hopf algebra in a braided monoidal category**) is wider and includes several other equally -imo-  common examples: If $G$ is a finite abelian group and $\theta$ is a bicharacter on $G$, then the Universal enveloping algebras (UEA) of the $g$-graded, $\theta$-colored Lie algebras are also such examples: they are braided groups or $\theta$-braided Hopf algebras. This is equivalent to saying that they are Hopf algebras in the braided monoidal Category $_{\mathbb{C}G}\mathcal{M}$ of representations of the quasitriangular group Hopf algebra $\mathbb{C}G$. (Note that here $\mathbb{C}G$ is considered "equipped" with its non-trivial quasitriangular structure). Some of the -historically- original examples of quantum groups, also fall into this or generalizations of this idea. For a review of the related definitions for braided hopf algebras you can see at this [article](http://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/1/1/74/htm) (see Proposition 3.2).

Now regarding your second question, on the relation of braided Hopf algebras with ordinary Hopf algebras: Generally, given a Hopf algebra $A$, in the braided monoidal Category $_{H}\mathcal{M}$ of the representations of the quasitriangular Hopf algebra $H$, there is a general method for constructing a smash product $A\star H$ algebra, in such a way that: $A\star H$ is an ordinary Hopf algebra and moreover there is an equivalence of Categories between the category of representations of $A\star H$ and the category of (braided) representations of $A$. This is known in the bibliography as **Majid's bosonization** or **Radford's biproduct**. You can see at this [article](http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~scaenepe/Kanakoglou.pdf) (see section 2, p.111-113) for a review of these methods.

Finally, regarding your last question: an ordinary Hopf algebra $H$, is a braided Hopf algebra (trivially), where the (symmetric) braiding is the usual twist map. This is equivalent to saying that, $H$ is a Hopf algebra in the symmetric monoidal category $_{\mathbb{C}G}\mathcal{M}$ of representations of the cocommutative group Hopf algebra $\mathbb{C}G$. Now, $\mathbb{C}G$ is considered "equipped" with its trivial quasitriangular structure (i.e. its cocommutativity), induced by the trivial $R$-matrix $R=1\otimes 1$.